# How to fix " Not enough memory resources to process this command"?

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net, serial-port

I have an application that communicates to device with SerialPort. 
I'm always sending commands and receive but after 2/3 hours I get the message that I wrote on the title.

I already tried to make some changes in my code but without success.

```vb
Private Sub timer_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles timer.Tick
  Call New Thread(Sub()
    SendCommand(command)
  End Sub).Start()
End Sub

Private Sub SendCommand(command as String)
  serialPort.DiscardInBuffer()
  serialPort.DiscardOutBuffer()
  serialPort.Write(command)
End Sub
```

The timer has 400 Milliseconds.
Everything works fine but after 2/3 hours I get the error:
Not enough memory resources to process this command

Problem fix:

```vb
Private Sub timer_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles timer.Tick
  Dim t = Task.Run(Sub()
    SendCommand(command)
  End Sub)
End Sub
```

Comment: Why use a System.Windows.Forms.Timer to create a background thread when you could just use a System.Threading.Timer which runs on a new thread already?

Comment: Thanks for your response.This is a DispatcherTimer (wpf)

Comment: With the very limited code above, it's hard to tell what is happening. I would do that first, then I would see if creating and disposing the serialPort inside SendCommand would help - and I bet it would solve the problem, but I'm not sure you want to do that every 400ms. Can you provide the code which creates the serialPort by editing your question?

Comment: I suspect you have a buffer of characters that is getting too big after 2/3 hours which is causing your error.  You didn't provide us with all the code, so I can't say which, but I would check that you clear your (command?) buffer after you send.

Comment: I tested the code you provided, but I faced other problems. Therefore, could you tell me where the serialport open? It is best for you to provide a completed code that could reproduce your problem.

Comment: Check Windows Task manager ( Threads and Handles) after some time, It can be that this threads don't finish or hanging and consume memory, i see somthing like that when you don't control them.

Comment: Sorry for delay. I just fix my problem changing the "Call New Thread" to Task.